# Как задать взаимосвязь между группой в LDAP и ролью пользователя в Spring Security

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, ldap

Данные для регистрации храняться в системе LDAP и пользователи поделены на множество групп, нужная

1. cn=finance_users

Как прописать, что если в LDAP пользователь принадлежит к группе finance_users то у него устанавливается роль ADMIN.

Comment: А что если вытащить роль админа из лдапа и добавить его в список ролей?

Comment: я написал метод для получения user name который был при регистрации, далее по идее можно сделать запрос к ldap и получить его группу. вот с последним не понимаю ка кточно запрос написать. у меня проблема я само содержимое ldap уидеть не могу оно приватное. мне нужно вернуть группу которая у данного пользователя. что то типа такого? List<String> strings = ldapTemplate.search(
                query().where("objectclass").is("person")
                        .and(query().where("username").is("???")),